What does a trailing slash mean when reading Python function documentation?
I'm reading the Python documentation in order to become familiar with the enormous library of functions and modules available. A few times I've seen a trailing slash in the parameter list, such as this:
str.removeprefix(prefix, /)

I don't see any mention of a second parameter in the documentation nor any mention of what this means. When I see this in the documentation, what is it documenting?
